# MVC Brettle NeatUpload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, neatupload

Has anyone used [NeatUpload](http://neatupload.codeplex.com/) for uploading a file with MVC2 or 3?
Or are there better alternatives?

If NeatUpload is good in combination with MVC can someone post an example?
Or if there's a better option can someone tell me about it?

Comment: If you use NeatUpload, I wrote a bit of an installation aide here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391657/how-to-install-neatupload/10400485#10400485.  Also, the post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254831/asp-net-free-ajax-file-upload-control/10388946#10388946 has some details about other uploaders.  I think NeatUpload is a very versatile uploader.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's better but SlickUpload can be used for uploading a file with MVC2/3 with some alteration to it's setup. I've found, however, that these solutions were developed for ASP.Net controls and they don't flow as nicely with the MVC pattern.

There is a post on this site that discusses doing it with the MVC design pattern, noting the comments about file size: [File Upload ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc3-0)

Comment: i want to control the size and format (of the image i want people to upload) before they bother to send it.

Comment: This is easy to do for file extensions with JavaScript, but for file size it can only be accomplished with the Flash or Silverlight type uploaders on the client. Otherwise for the file size you will have to detect on the server side and send a message back to the user before streaming the file.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you use to upload you should use a queue system as you can get bottle necked from taking too many uploads at the same time.[Document that will explain more](http://www.freewebdevelopersite.com/tag/iis/)

Comment: That's something i can deal with overtime because i don't expect any concurrent uploads anytime soon.