# Uploading files with Windows Phone BackgroundTransfer service to an MVC3 site in a RESTful manner

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, windows-phone-7, rest, upload, background-transfer

I need my Windows Phone application to be able to upload audio files to my MVC3 site, using the BackgroundTransferService available in Mango.

As one possible solution, I can:

1. Map a route to my controller:

   ```
   public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
           {
               context.MapRoute(
                   "SingleAudioFile",
                   "Api/Audio/Recieve",
                   new { controller = "AudioFiles", action = "Recieve" }
                   );
           }
   ```
2. In the controller, have a Recieve action

   ```
   [HttpPost]    
   public JsonResult Recieve(byte[] audio)
        {
            // saving and status report logic here
        }
   ```

**My question is**: How do I set the system to bind file I upload from Windows Phone to a `Recieve` action's `audio` byte[] parameter?

On the phone, the data is being uploaded the following way:

```
BackgroundTransferRequest btr = new BackgroundTransferRequest (new Uri
                 (siteUrl + "Api/Audio/Recieve",UriKind.Absolute));
    btr.TransferPreferences = TransferPreferences.AllowBattery;
    btr.Method = "POST";
    btr.UploadLocation = new Uri("/" + Transfers + "/" + isoAudioFileName, UriKind.Relative);
Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundTransferService.Add(btr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what protocol does the BackgroundTransfer use to send the file but if it writes the buffer directly to the body of the POST request you could use a custom model binder to read directly from the request stream:

```
public class BTModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
            return ms.GetBuffer();
        }
    }
}
```

which could be registered like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Receive([ModelBinder(typeof(BTModelBinder))] byte[] audio)
{
    ...
}
```

If it uses `multipart/form-data` then you could use a standard `HttpPostedFileBase` action parameter as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc3-0/5193851#5193851).

Comment: Thank you Darin. I will try the approach today and will get back to mark an answer if it works. As for BackgroundTransferService, Microsoft guys have released a training kit with BTS lab, but didn't provide a source code for server side, so there is no way to see how to implement a server processing, without further research.