# Empty file when Request.Files

Tags: c#, forms, file, upload, request

I'm working with C# and MVC3 and I'm trying to upload a text file that I know is not empty, but when I access the file (when debugging) via `Request.Files["Cv"].ContentLength` is 0.

How come this happens? I know the file is not empty, as it has some text strings there but I need to check that there..

Thanks a lot everybody in advance.

Best,
Manuel

Comment: Are you sure that Request.Files["CV"] exists? Also could you show the code around this.

Comment: Have you verified that the file is actually being sent to the server?  I would recommend checking this first, typically I inspect the HTTP traffic between my browser and web app using fiddler.

Comment: @msarchet yes, I can see the name of the file that I'm trying to upload, the `ContentType` and the rest of attributes.

Comment: Please show your code. View and controller action.

Comment: I'm using two controllers for two parts of my web app that are using the same code for the uploading; I'm uploading the same file and it's working on one controller, but not in the other :)

Comment: @noloman, I didn't ask if it is working or not. I asked to see your code please. I asked an example that will allow me to reproduce your problem. Because I can point you to an answer illustrating that this works without any issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc3-0/5193851#5193851. So apparently the problem is with your code. And without seeing your code I don't see how I can help you.

Comment: Please post header from Fiddler.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured the problem out by myself: it was a matter of initializing the model in the right place.. thanks everybody for your help!

Comment: Could you please show the code for your solution, as this is a question and answer site.

Comment: This answer adds no knowledge whatsoever.