# Asp.net MVC 3 how pass http post request from remote client from a view (razor) page to the controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, http, request

When a http post request from a remote client arrived, I want to pass this reqeuest (upload some files) to the controller to process. What shall I do in the view page using razor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HttpContext is automatically available in your Controller, just use the `HttpContext` property.

Likewise, the HttpRequest is available through the `Request` property.

Comment: Thx.Can you give me some code examples? I am a newbie of razor.

Comment: How to upload a file in MVC 3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc3-0

Comment: I have seen the example. But my post request is coming from the remote client process and do not require the 'input' page. Sorry for my pool english.

Comment: That is to say, the coming request is constructed by another application but not the 'input submit' click action.