# I want to insert uploaded image in root directory images folder and its path to image column in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, razor

how can i make an uploading image page via razor syntax (CSHTML) to simply upload file to /image root with increasing name like  imgxxxyyy.jpg  when the img part is fixed and xxx is the id of the inserting/updating product  and yyy is the increasing number of image of that product and store the path to the imagpath column in my table ?

more i think about it and i research about it i get more confused .... please help me in this case .

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc3-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier if you used Guids for filenames. So you could define a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

a view containing a form where the user will be able to select a file to upload:

```
@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.File)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.File, new { type = "file" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.File)
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
}
```

and finally a controller to show the form and process the upload:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        if (model.File != null && model.File.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var imageFolder = Server.MapPath("~/image");
            var ext = Path.GetExtension(model.File.FileName);
            var file = Path.ChangeExtension(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ext);
            var fullPath = Path.Combine(imageFolder, file);
            model.File.SaveAs(fullPath);

            // Save the full path of the uploaded file
            // in the database. Obviously this code should be externalized
            // into a repository but for the purposes of this example
            // I have left it in the controller
            var connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDb"].ConnectionString;
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO images VALUES (@path)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", fullPath);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```