# Uploading image in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a Upload form and I want to pass my information such as an Image and some other field but I don't know how can I upload Image ..

this is my controller code :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(tblPortfolio tblportfolio)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.tblPortfolios.AddObject(tblportfolio);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");  
            }

            return View(tblportfolio);
        }
```

And this is my view code :

```
@model MyApp.Models.tblPortfolio

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>tblPortfolio</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageFile)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImageFile, new { type = "file" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageFile)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Link)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Link)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Link)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Now I don't know how can I upload Image and save it on server .. how can I set Image name by `Guid.NewGuid();` ? Or how can I set Image Path ?

Comment: What's the type of `model.ImageFile`?

Comment: @Shimmy: I just save image name in database . it's string .

Comment: I ended up generating a GUID for each new image and saving its name in the database. The folder isn't saved to the server, just the image file name. The folder is dynamically injected.

Comment: **[Uploading multiple files upload in asp.net mvc 4 razor provides client-side validation too.](http://lesson8.blogspot.in/2013/05/how-to-create-and-editorfor-fileupload.html)**

Comment: checkout my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40990080/4251431

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Firstly, you'll need to change your view to include the following:

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

Then you'll need to change your post `ActionMethod` to take a `HttpPostedFileBase`, like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(tblPortfolio tblportfolio, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    //you can put your existing save code here
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) 
    {
        //do whatever you want with the file
    }
}
```

Comment: I use your code and I think it works correctly but it show to me an error : Access to the path 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ND\MyApp\MyApp\Uploads' is denied. Do you know why ? why it shows to me this error on local ?

Comment: Hmmm, You need to find out from the application pool for the website what is the identity it is running under (by default this is Application Pool Identity) and grant that the correct permissions.

Comment: I Change my Application Pool Identity to Localsystem .. I red somewhere about this that I must change it to localsystem but it's not working .. any suggestion ?

Comment: Hmm, look here http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/ and make sure you've followed all those steps, that should work fine :)

Comment: @Persian Good stuff! Glad I could help :)

Comment: Here's some more information http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can get it from `Request` using `Request.Files` Collection, In case of single file upload just read from the first index using `Request.Files[0]`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(tblPortfolio tblportfolio) 
{
 if(Request.Files.Count > 0)
 {
 HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
 if (file != null) 
 { 
  // business logic here  
 }
 } 
}
```

In case of Multiple files uploading, you have to iterate on the `Request.Files` collection:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Create(tblPortfolio tblportfolio)
{ 
 for(int i=0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
 {
   HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];
   if (file != null)
   {
    // Do something here
   }
 }
}
```