# Upload Images in asp.net mvc 3 aspx syntax for custom class without database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having a problem uploading images in ASP.NET MVC 3. Currently I have a class called `EmployeeModel` which has the properties for employees:

```
public class EmployeeModel       //Model for employee information
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "ID Required")]
    public int ID { get; set; }//Employee Id

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name Required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z\s]+$", ErrorMessage = "Name can have only alphabets and spaces")]
    public string Name { get; set; }//Employee Name

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }//Employee Date of birth

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DOJ { get; set; }//Employee Date of Joining

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address Requried")]
    public string Address { get; set; }//Employee Address

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Mobile Number Requried")]
    [RegularExpression(@"[0-9]{10}", ErrorMessage = "Mobile number not valid")]
    public double Mobile { get; set; }//Employee Mobile number

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Requried")]
    [RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", ErrorMessage = "Email Id not  valid")]
    public string Email { get; set; }//Employee Email-ID

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Designation Requried")]
    public string Designation { get; set; }//Employee Designation

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Salary Required")]
    public double Salary { get; set; }//Employee Salary        
}
```

The requirement is that I need to upload an image for each employee and display them. I'm using a text file to store the information of the employee (acting as a database).

Comment: OK. What have you tried?

Comment: i have tried googling various websites but nothing useful

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these articles can help: [this](http://cpratt.co/file-uploads-in-asp-net-mvc-with-view-models/) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/708140/Uploading-and-Viewing-Images-With-ASP-Net-MVC-and).

The one from CodeProject uses MongoDB, but I think you can ignore that parts and get what you want. It seems simple enough.

And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402094/uploading-image-in-asp-net-mvc) is the most simple one from SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `HttpPostedFileBase` property in your model. 
And in your POST action use :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action_name", "Controler_name", FormMethod.Post, 
                                   new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
// your form data here
}
```

Comment: i would like to implement the image uploading as a part of my create view

Comment: You might missing something.Read this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304617/html-helper-for-input-type-file . may help you