# how to send Image bytes using query string

Tags: c#, json, post, asp.net-web-api

I am new in developing Rest service using web api in asp .net .

I try to send image byte with in the query string.but i could not abe to send  image byte with in query string.

I have Basic concept in GET And Post.

Post don't have any limitation to send data.

Herewith i have added my sample code also.

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
public string PostRoute(string routingRequestTemplate)
{
    return routingRequestTemplate;
}
```

My string value:

```
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
```

**url:**
http://localhost:64528/api/controller/PostRoute?routingRequestTemplate=string

following error I got

**Request filtering is configured on the Web server to deny the request because the query string is too long.**

Comment: Why do you need to send an image with a `GET` request?

Comment: @ Vsevolod Goloviznin i need post method only.how can i change Post instead of Get

Comment: So just post it, what's the problem?

Comment: As @VsevolodGoloviznin points out you should be POST-ing your data because you are posting data to the server, not getting data from it? Remove the "GET" from the accept verbs and POST your data rather than hit from a browser URL.

Comment: @ Belogix  [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
        public string PostRoute(string routingRequestTemplate)
        {
            return routingRequestTemplate;
        }  same error I got

Comment: You say same error, what's the error? Add it to your question.

Comment: You're adding the parameter as a query string parameter, not as a body of a `POST` request

Answer (score 0):

**Querystring have limition of size, below is details**

*Maximum length of Querystring is based on the browser not depend upon the asp.net.*

1. Maximum length of a querystring in IE 4.0 and above is ~2048 characters
2. IE. 4,5,6,7, - 2,048 characters.
3. Opera supports - 4050 characters.
4. Netscape 6 supports - 2000 characters.
5. Firefox Supports - 6000 characters

Try below codes  with Post verb :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostRoute(HttpPostedFileBase file) {


}
```

this link will also help you :

[Uploading image in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402094/uploading-image-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

[What is the maximum possible length of a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string)

Your image will need to be quite small, and base64 encoded, or made url safe. URL length is quite limited. I would suggest putting it in a POST body.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64