# WebAPI Maximum Request Length for single endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using WebAPI 2 and have an endpoint that allows users to upload files. I certainly have business rules that determine how large the file can be based on which user is making the request, but ultimately they can be upward of 20-50 megabytes.

Is there a way to increase the maximum request length for only a specific WebAPI action only? I don't really feel like increasing the web configuration's 'maxRequestLength' is the right answer, because I really only need this single endpoint to allow large requests. I don't want to allow such large, senseless requests on my other endpoints

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC3 Action File Size Limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825849/mvc3-action-file-size-limit)