# Upload image and save in database in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, image, file-upload, image-uploading

I want to add the ability to upload an image and save it in my database. I have a table and one of its columns is an Image data type. I followed [this link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1679447.aspx/1), and some similar links, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is the code I tried:

```
if (Request.Files.Count > 0 && Request.Files[0] != null)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), file.FileName);
    file.SaveAs(path);
}
```

But the file doesn't save in the specified folder.

Comment: try debugging. what path string path variable contains? Is Request.Files empty? Please provide some more details.

Comment: Do you receive an exception? Why save the file in a folder when you want to save in a database table?

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc3-0/5193851#5193851

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure the `encType` is set to `multipart/form-data` in the HTML form.

Ex.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
      new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```