# C# MVC3 File Input html control-Potential Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a file upload control, when users hit browse and select the file residing on their machine. After that I have a button which posts back to an action method and parses through the file and the populates a few fields in the model on the page.  Then they hit the save button and It saves the files since I persist the file path in a hidden field. My problem is in my local development environment everything works fine. When I deploy it on a server, The code does not parse the file. Is it possible that the file is not being parsed because server cannot directly open and read a file which exists on users machine?

Thank you

Comment: Might want to check permissions.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that the file is not being parsed because server cannot directly open and read a file which exists on users machine?

Exactly. If you want to save the file, save it during the first post.
You can't just read up a file from the user's computer from a webpage.

#### Edit:

Check this answer about how to do file upload in MVC3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5193851/618331

Comment: Ahhh Ok, What I was doing was providing the parser the exact filename from the file upload input box