# MVC3: how to upload multiple files with or without uploadify

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, uploadify

I've spend hours trying to make uploadify work, but all I see is a button that says [Select File] and that does nothing. Found some links like [Multiple file upload in MVC using Uploadify](http://techblog.edwardting.com/2011/05/20/multiple-file-upload-in-mvc-using-uploadify/) and [Using uploadify with ASP.Net2](http://zootfroot.blogspot.nl/2010/12/mvc-file-upload-using-uploadify-with.html) resulting in the same. And with the information from uploadify.com it doesn't work either. So I'm stuck at uploadify.

I also noticed that most info is at least one year old. Now I'm wondering if this is THE way to go, or can you recommend a better way? Currently I'm looking at [File upload asp.net mvc3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc3-0) which looks really nice and simple, but only lets you upload 1 file at a time...

Kind regards,

Paul.

Comment: Can you share us the code that what did you tried for uploadify?

Comment: I've had good luck with plupload. I've used it in MVC3 apps and used each method on the client (html5, flash, silverlight, etc..)

Comment: I wonder how u missed Phil Haack's [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) for this ? what keywords you used for the search..

Comment: Yep, it came accross. But I want to be able to upload multiple, not resctricted to 2.

Comment: I will now investigate plupload. Didn´t came accross that one. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**One approach is:**

According to Phil Haack http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx

You can do this:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <label for="file1">Filename:</label>
 <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />

 <label for="file2">Filename:</label>
 <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />

 <input type="submit"  />
 </form>
```

And the controller..

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files) {
 foreach (var file in files) {
 if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
   var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
   var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
   file.SaveAs(path);
 }
}
return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**Second approach:**

Using KendoUI's upload. It allows upload multiples files synchronously and asynchronously.

The Upload can be used as a drop-in replacement for file input elements.

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/upload/index.html

**Clarification:** No version of IE supports multiple file selection.

Comment: Both of these approaches will work.  We actually uses the Telerik MVC extensions, which were the precursor to the Kendo UI library, at work and they work pretty well.

Comment: That's right. I migrated from Telerik to Kendo UI extensions a month ago.

Comment: Sorry, just came back from holiday. Gave Uploadify another try today, still won´t work right.

Ofcourse came accross Phil Haack´s simple solution for multiple files. Indeed 2 is a multiple, but I want to be able to really select multiple, not just 2.

Comment: @keun I just tried kendo upload's demo and could select 3 files. Did you see this?  http://demos.kendoui.com/web/upload/async.html

Comment: @Pabloker Yes saw that. But the dialog will only let me choose 1 file each time. When clicking select-button a second time I can choose another one. Kind of a hassle when I want 20 for example.

Comment: @keun I just tried again, and I could select 3 files at the same time and Kendo Upload (async) added them perfectly. Try to select the files using “shift” in the selection dialog. (Use this example http://demos.kendoui.com/web/upload/async.html)

Comment: @Pabloker Hmmmm.. IE just lets me select one. In FF I can select multiple but only 1 occurs... :-s

Comment: @keun I'm using Chrome. According to Telerik support _IE does not support multiple file selection in the browse dialog_ so sad.