# How to Upload Files in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [File Upload ASP.NET MVC 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc-3-0)

I am trying to just print out the name of the file in the debugger to make sure I am getting it this far:

```
<EmployeeAuthorize()>
<HttpPost()>
Function SendNewMessage(ByVal file1 As HttpPostedFileBase) As JsonResult


    Dim fileName = Path.GetFileName(file1.FileName)
    Debug.Print(fileName)

    Return Nothing

End Function
```

I am sending the data with this:

```
var file1 = $('#file1').val();

            $(this).parent('li').hide();
            $('#pleaseWait').show();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Message/SendNewMessage',
                type: 'post',
                data: { file1: file1 },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    // update with results
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(result));
                    $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                        // do nothing
                    });
                    $('#myDiv').html(JSON.stringify(result));

                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert('An error occurred when updating the database.  Please contact technical support.  ');

                }
            });
```

It doesn't print any data in my console.  It gives a `NullReferenceException` so I can assume it's not getting the filename at all.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files cannot be uploaded directly through ajax. Instead of it you should use iframe or flash or jquery special plugins.

For example you can accomplish ajax file uploading through [jquery forms](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload) plugin.

Try this, it works:

```
Public Class MessageController Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    Function SendNewMessage(ByVal file1 As HttpPostedFileBase) As JsonResult


        Dim fileName = Path.GetFileName(file1.FileName)
        Debug.Print(fileName)

        Return Nothing

    End Function

End Class
```

and this in your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function () {
        var options = {
            beforeSubmit: function (formData, jqForm, options) { },  // pre-submit callback 
            success: function (responseText, statusText, xhr, form) { }   // post-submit callback 
        };
        // bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
        $('#uploadForm').ajaxForm(options);
    });
</script>

<form action="/Message/SendNewMessage" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="uploadForm" >
    <input type="file" name="file1" />
    <input type="submit" value="send" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Is that a native jQuery method (ajaxForm) because I can't find any documentation anywhere.  Do I need to use a plugin?

Comment: Is it this?  http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started

Comment: yes, you should download from here http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js