# Copy original image in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting in controller as parameter image upload and I need to copy that image so I can manipulate on copy not on original. How can I copy image in mvc?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase photo)
{
  var copiedImage = ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SaveAs()` function of the `HttpPostedFileBase` class to store the image on the server on a separate location and then manipulate it.

See this SO post

[File Upload ASP.NET MVC 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc-3-0)

In the second post there is a piece of code to copy the file to another stream

```
 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
     file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
     byte[] array = ms.GetBuffer(); }
```