# jquery.ajax and asp mvc 4. post files

Tags: jquery, file-io, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to know how to post files from an input to an **asp mvc4 controller**. Please I would thanks help

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx

Comment: a search on google get you lacks of results

Comment: but i need code example, no plugins

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use AJAX to send files to the server. This is possible only in browsers that support the [`HTML5 File API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications). As an alternative there are plugins that you could use such as [`jQuery.form`](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/), [`Uploadify`](http://www.uploadify.com/), [`Fine Uploader`](http://fineuploader.com/), [`BlueImp file upload`](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) which will test the capabilities of the client browser and fallback to other techniques if it doesn't support HTML5 File API.

Comment: I don't want to use a plugin, i need a code example for c# asp.net mvc 4

Comment: As I already mentioned in my answer it is not possible to upload files using AJAX. If you want to upload files with a standard form you may take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc-3-0/