# MVC3 and EF // Add an Image to an existing database object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image, entity-framework

Model

```
   public class Discount

    {
    public int DiscountId {get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Information { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to add an image to this model that does not exist yet.  For instance when a user browses to the CRUD page Create View, the user can create a new Discount and it will have the option to browse/upload a new image that will be identified with the new discount created.

[File Upload ASP.NET MVC 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc-3-0/5193851#5193851)
has taught me how to upload images in MVC3 but I am needing assistance on mapping this uploaded image to a specific discount (DiscountID).

Comment: You need to create an `Entity` for `Images` and then create a relationship between `Discount and Image`. Or you can create an `Array Image property` within the `Discount Entity`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your actual requirement is, but you can give image name based on the DB id. Eg. `Img0001` etc.. Also, save the path of that image file in the related record in the DB.