# The following throws 'is a Method but treated like a type'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

The most confusing error I have ever seen in ASP. I have done method calls like this before, and have no issue in other spots of my code.

First of all the class:

```
namespace LocApp.Helpers.Classes.LocationHelper
{
    public class QueryHelper
    {
        private LocAppContext db = new LocAppContext();

        public static IEnumerable<Service> getAllService()
        {
            using (var db = new LocAppContext())
            {
                var service = db.Locations.Include(s => s.LocationAssignment);

                var serv = (from s in db.Services
                            where s.active == true
                            select s).ToList();
                return serv;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pretty easy to understand whats going on. So lets call the method:

```
IEnumerable<LocApp.Models.Service> Service = new LocApp.Helpers.Classes.LocationHelper.QueryHelper.getAllService(Model.id);
```

`getAllServices(Model.id)` is throwing the error "is a method but treated like a type" , um no its not be treated like a type....

whats going on?

Comment: `getAllService()` does not have any input parameters, but you are trying to pass `id` to this method

Comment: For future reference: you should post the exact errors that you're getting, and you'll probably want to distinguish between *compilation* errors and *runtime* errors for people. (Here it's not compiling).  You can tell the difference based on whether or not you can run it.  (remember "Build and Run" is two separate steps)

Comment: possible duplicate of [File Upload ASP.NET MVC 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc-3-0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it's exactly as the error message says. `getAllService()` is a method:

```
public static IEnumerable<Service> getAllService()
```

But you're trying to use it as if it were a type with a constructor:

```
Service = new LocApp.Helpers.Classes.LocationHelper.QueryHelper.getAllService(...)
```

The `new` part is the mistake here. You don't want to call a constructor, you just want to call a method. It's a static method, so you don't need an instance - you can just use:

```
Service = LocApp.Helpers.Classes.LocationHelper.QueryHelper.getAllService(...)
```

Note that if you have appropriate `using` directives, follow .NET naming conventions and take care about singular/plural names, your code will be easier to follow:

```
var services = QueryHelper.GetAllServices(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you not simply mean:

```
IEnumerable<LocApp.Models.Service> Service = LocApp.Helpers.Classes.LocationHelper.QueryHelper.getAllService();
```

Get rid of the `new` bit, essentially, and that method doesn't take any parameters either - I'd assume you'd run into that problem after you removed the `new` bit.

Answer (score 1):

Your getAllService method doesn't take any arguments, so you should call it without. Also it is a static method so don't use the `new` keyword:

```
IEnumerable<LocApp.Models.Service> Service = LocApp.Helpers.Classes.LocationHelper.QueryHelper.getAllService();
```