# upload files in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-4

I'd like to upload a file in asp.net mvc. I've the following codes. But `file` returns always `null` value. Is there anything, I should try?

.cshtml

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
```

controller.cs

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(BookModel model, HttpPostedFileBase file, FormCollection values)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View("Index", new BookModel());
            }

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {                    
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);                    
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/img/"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);

                model.ImageUrl = fileName;
            }


         //SendMail();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {               
            return View("Index", new BookModel());
        }

        return View("Success");
    }
```

Comment: could you share View Form code?

Comment: I think your form element not contain `enctype = "multipart/form-data"`

Comment: look at Darin's solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc-3-0/5193851#5193851

Comment: is your <input> object into the <form>?

Answer (score 3):

Add to form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`