# file upload with MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add file upload to my asp.net mvc4, however, since I am just learning C# I am not sure on how where to add it:

This is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.c_id = new SelectList(db.Cities.OrderBy(o => o.name), "c_id", "name");
            ViewBag.m_id = new SelectList(db.Schools, "m_id", "name");

            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(TotalReport treport)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                treport.created = DateTime.Now;

                db.TotalReports.Add(treport);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.c_id = new SelectList(db.Cities.OrderBy(o => o.name), "c_id", "name");
            ViewBag.m_id = new SelectList(db.Schools, "m_id", "name");

            return View(treport);
        }
```

the view is here:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
<div class="mycss">
        <input type="file" name="file" />
     </div>
</fieldset>
```

ok here is the part that saves the file:

```
if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // extract only the fielname
                var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
                var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/myfolder"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose if your markup is like,

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

and then your action should look like,

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
    string filename=file.FileName;
    filename=DateTime.Now.ToString("YYYY_MM_dddd_hh_mm_ss")+filename;
    file.SaveAs("your path"+filename);
return View();
    }
```

here parameter name of HttpPostedFileBase  and upload control name should be same. Hope this helps

Comment: i am able to upload the file and all, however, it doesn't get saved!

Comment: Did you get file data into file parameter? and check the path is existed or not.

Comment: yes the file gets into the parameter, and all. however, when i check the folder, it is not there. i am on windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

pick up the files in the controller like so

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                treport.created = DateTime.Now;

                db.TotalReports.Add(treport);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.c_id = new SelectList(db.Cities.OrderBy(o => o.name), "c_id", "name");
            ViewBag.m_id = new SelectList(db.Schools, "m_id", "name");

            return View(treport);
        }
```

Comment: how about my existing declaration: "TotalReport treport" where does it go?

Comment: so i did, however, the file didn't get uploaded:( there were no errors, yet when i check the folder it was blank. forgot to this is done on localhost, so you do think that is why? localhost is my local PC, not production.

Comment: Sorry, you can add your model in as a parem as well

Answer (score 0):

just add argument for the posted file to your action :

```
public ActionResult Create(TotalReport treport, System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase file)
```

and do whatever you want to do with it - read stream, save it somewhere...

Comment: ok got it! this also helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc-3-0

Comment: i was trying to do this:  var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName); in my code however, it says "path does not exist in current content", how do i include it: system.path?

Comment: so i did, however, the file didn't get uploaded:( there were no errors, yet when i check the folder it was blank. forgot to this is done on localhost, so you do think that is why? localhost is my local PC, not production.

Comment: I added the part that saves the file, please see above