# Optional HttpPostedFileBase in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Web API written in MVC.
I have a post action with some optional arguments.

```
public Guid PostExecution(string Action, List<Guid> ComputersIDs, int Port = 0, string Command = null, string Password = null)
```

It works perfectly. Now I need this action to receive an optional file sent through the post method.

So:

```
public Guid PostExecution(string Action, List<Guid> ComputersIDs, int Port = 0, string Command = null, string Password = null, HttpPostedFileBase file = null)
```

The interesting thing is that when I add the parameter `HttpPostedFileBase` the servers stops the responds the requests to this action and only says Error 500 Internal Server error. It doesn't thrown any exception. With a breakpoint the code doesn't enter to the `PostExecution`.

Why does this happen?

How can I debug this error?

Is it possible to have an optional `HttpPostedFileBase`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all posted files are optional!

and you can get them by `Request.Files`, and you don't need to have them in methods parameter

Comment: Explain me a little more please. I used to do something like public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file) according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/5193851/909974

Comment: Well, that is the binding magic of asp.net mvc! but you want to use that when you are certain there will be a file, actually that binding it self gets the files from Request.Files too, and just make the method a little easier to read and follow,if the user does not send any file with that special name (of the input type=file) the action will not be found and 404 error goes back to the client