# How to POST a file to asp.net mvc app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm posting a simple text file to an asp.net MVC app.  When I post using the form below, the form parameter is not null.  But *file* is.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
<form method=post action="http://localhost/Home/ProcessIt" 
enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"> 
<input type=file id="thefile" name="thefile" /> 
<input type="submit" name="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

In the asp.net mvc app:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessIt(FormCollection thefile)
{
  HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["thefile"];
  ...
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc-3-0/5193851#5193851

Comment: If I use HttpPostedFileBase, the parameter will be null.

Comment: use the same name for your input element and method parameter. Follow the link i posted

Comment: I've updated the post.  I am using the same ID/Name for the input element and method parameter.  Still no file.

Comment: Got it working with FormCollection.  IE was caching my form fields.  Once I refreshed, it began working.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    // Verify that the user selected a file
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) 
    {
        // extract only the fielname
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

        // then save on the server...
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploads"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);
    }
    // redirect back to the index action to show the form once again
    return RedirectToAction("Index");        
}
```

Comment: Instead of copying and pasting solutions as your own you should really point to the original. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5193851/1759873

Answer (score 0):

Need to change the `enctype` to `multipart/form-data`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2

Comment: file is still null.  There isn't anything in the Request.Files collection.