# how to add image as byte[] in userprofile and then upload and display it in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, image-uploading, user-profile

I want to complete this code step by step to add an image as byte array in an userprofile as profile pic of every user. What I have so far:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

Now how to complete code for controler?
How to complete code for view?
How to complete code for edit view?

Thanks if someone have the time to help me.

Comment: Are you asking us to code the controller, view, or edit view?  Or are you asking us which order they should be created in?

Comment: if complete code possible then i will be very thankful to you

Comment: I suggest to do some Google instated bagging for code. Try & think a bit .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For showing image

```
@{
    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image);
    var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);
}

<img src="@imgSrc" />
```

Some Reference for your help :

[Upload image included in MVC model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446580/upload-image-included-in-mvc-model)