# jquery fileupload Images Uploaded to Server Not Showing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

I am able to add files and upload them to my website correctly however existing images on the server do not display in the table correctly. They show as blank rows in the table.
href is 'file:///D:/Hosting/11318691/html/Images/Penguins.jpg' when I believe it should be
'http://www.mywebsite.com/Images/Penguins.jpg'. I am using Godaddy if that matters.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you here?

Comment: Is there some setting in jquery.fileupload.js to control this behavior? Here is a link to my image upload page that shows this behavior. http://www.stuffwant.com/Items/Images Notice if you move your mousepointer to the left side of the rows the image paths are file:///D:/Hosting... Why is jquery.fileupload behaving like this?

Comment: I don't know, check plugin DOC. Now if you want more relevant help, provide your relevant code, seems obvious

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the .html file so the images will look like `<img src="/Images/Penguins.jpg'" >` rather than `<img src="file:///D:/Hosting/11318691/html/Images/Penguins.jpg'" >`. What web editing software are you using?

Comment: My site is an ASP.NET MVC Web Application. I am trying to use the file upload controller https://github.com/blackcity/Backload. It is based on the jQuery File Upload Plugin. Go to http://www.stuffwant.com/Items/Images and then view the page source.

Comment: I just uploaded an image, works fine for me.

Comment: If you refresh the page does your uploaded image show in the table or do you get a row without the image showing?

Comment: Ohhh I see now, my bad.

Comment: Is your site hosted on a Windows server?

Comment: I think the issue is where you take the file path and store it in the database. You have to remove the 'D:/Hosting...' either before saving to database or when displaying.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc-3-0

`var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);`