# Upload file using Dojo and c# using xhr Post

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, dojo

I'm trying to upload file using dojo/_base/xhr
here is the code:

```
 xhr.post({
                url: postUrl,
                handleAs: "text",
                contentType: "application/json",
                timeout: 10000,
                postData: dojo.toJson({ file: Uploader.files[0]}),
                load: function (result) {
                    show image...
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    show error...
                }
            });
```

when I try to send `Uploader.files[0].size` I get the value I should get, but when I try to send `Uploader.files[0]` or `Uploader.files[0]` I get null.

On the server side:

```
[HttpPost]
public string UploadImg(string file)
{
`   Saving file
}
```

I tried everything!! But I can't manage to get the file itself. `Request.Files` returns 0 files. Submitting a form isn't an option and when I use

```
 xhr.post({
                form: dom.byId("myform"),
                handleAs: "text",
                timeout: 10000,
                load: function (result) {
                    show image...
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    show error...
                }
```

`Request.Files` returns 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajax is not a viable option for crossbrowser file async upload. you should try using the module:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/request/iframe.html

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/iframe.html

and make them submit your form to a hidden iframe.

```
iframe(postUrl,{
  form: "theForm",
  handleAs: "text"
}).then(function(data){
  show image...
},function(err){
  show error...
});
```

just remember that if you need to do something with the returning data(and is not html [like in your text case]) you need to do this for the response:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <textarea>
         data
    </textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this because I'm using c#? I saw many tutorials for this kind of file upload with php.

Comment: it is possible to do using html5 file api, but this is not cross browser reliable, therefore not implemented by dojo(maybe its somewhere as a kind of shim)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using HttpPostedFileBase :

```
[HttpPost]
public string UploadImg(HttpPostedFileBase file) {
   //Save the file :
   if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) {
      file.SaveAs(path);
   }
}
```

See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5193851), and [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/)

You could also try removing the dojo.toJson :

```
postData: { file: Uploader.files[0]}
```

Instead of :

```
postData: dojo.toJson({ file: Uploader.files[0]})
```