# Ajax style upload equiv to XmlHttpRequest for file uploading to MVC controller? Uploading via ajax to MVC controller solved

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

Right now I have multiple forms on a page that I want to be rid of.  So currently I'm doing this.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
  $("button[id$='uploadfile']").click(function (evt) {
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // This code block works
        alert("upload file");
        var file1 = $('#csvIdentifierFileBase').val();
        var formData = new FormData();
        var opmlFile = $('#csvIdentifierFileBase')[0];
        formData.append("opmlFile", opmlFile.files[0]);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'alt/Import');
        xhr.send(formData);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        };
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // This code block does not
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'alt/Import',
            data: formData,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            //cache: false,
            //contentType: false,
            //processData: false,
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result.success);
            },
            error: function (a, b, c) {
                alert("An error has occurred.");
            }
        });
```

**HTML**

```
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="file" name="csvIdentifierFileBase" id="csvIdentifierFileBase"/>
            <button id="uploadfile" name="action" value="Import" >Import</button>
        </div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Import()//HttpPostedFileBase csvIdentifierFileBase)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0]; //Uploaded file
    }
```

Not changing anything besides the javscript call to this controller method, and using the XmlHttpRequest it works fine, is there a way to switch to a jquery/ajax style call so I'm not relying on the XmlHttpRequest object and still have it call into the controller?  I'm looking for a native solution and not another type of plugin... is that possible?  **also can't wrap the input and button in a AJAX.BeginForm tag as I'm trying to eliminate the number of forms on one page.**

Comment: I have just posted the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23007332/how-to-upload-file-via-mvc4-and-get-json-response/23008287#23008287 also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042116/ajax-beginform-in-mvc-to-upload-files/19044689#19044689

Comment: I can't use the Ajax.beginform as I would then end up with a form within a form and that doesn't work.  That is why I'm doing the above without a form tag.  I need to be able to do what you did Ashwini on that post only without the form tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will help someone else out there as I spent quite some time on this.  Here is how to post a file via $.ajax WITHOUT any additional plugin, and WITHOUT an Ajax.BeginForm tag in the html view.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    $("button[id$='uploadfile']").click(function (evt) {
    alert("upload file");
    // relatively irrelevant name used here but is not what model binder uses in MVC
    var file_data = $("#csvIdentifierFileBase").prop("files")[0];   // Getting the properties of file from file field
    var form_data = new FormData();                  // Creating object of FormData class
    // THIS IS IMPORTANT, THE NAME HERE **"file"** IS WHAT THE MODEL BINDER USES IN MVC CONTROLLER
    form_data.append("file", file_data);            // Appending parameter named file with properties of file_field to form_data
    //form_data.append("user_id", 123);             // Adding extra parameters to form_data
    $.ajax({
        url: "alt/Import",
        dataType: 'script',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,                            // Setting the data attribute of ajax with file_data
        type: 'post'
    });
});
```

**HTML**  **NO FORM TAGS NO PLUGGINS**

```
         // name and id of input type file relatively irrelevant 
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="file" name="csvIdentifierFileBase" id="csvIdentifierFileBase"/>
            <button id="uploadfile" name="action" value="Import" >Import</button>
        </div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase file) // THIS VAIRABLE NAME HAS TO BE THE SAME AS WHAT IS PASSED IN VIA THE SCRIPT FOR FORM DATA
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0]; //Uploaded file JUST A SECOND WAY TO ACCESS THE SAME INFORMATION THAT IS COMING IN AS HttpPostedFileBase file
    }
```

**HOWEVER here's the GIT**
FormData() is not supported in IE so this approach will not work for IE

Supporting information can be found here
http://blog.w3villa.com/websites/uploading-filesimage-with-ajax-jquery-without-submitting-a-form/

**IE ALTERNATIVE TO ABOVE**

**HTML**

```
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="file" name="csvIdentifierFileBase" id="csvIdentifierFileBase"/>
            <button id="uploadfile" name="action" value="Import" >Import</button>
        </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$("button[id$='uploadfile']").click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var $newForm = $('<form>', {
        'action': 'alt/Import',
        'method': 'post',
        'enctype': 'multipart/form-data',
        'target':'_top'
//dynamically appending the input type file to the dynamically generated form and it MUST be appended to the page to work. "appendTo(body") submit then remove
 }).append($("#csvIdentifierFileBase")).appendTo('body').submit().remove();
```

});

**NOW THE NAME DOES MATTER**

Since the input element is being dynamically added to the form the name does have to match the controller method param name for the model binder to work.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase csvIdentifierFileBase)
{

}
```

Fundamentally no different then having a form tag around the inputs which is the situation I'm trying to avoid.  The reason I'm doing it this way and why I was trying to avoid multiple forms on a page was because I was in a situation where I would have had nested form tags which will not work.

Comment: This is perfect!  This exactly what I was looking for!  I too didn't want to use plugins or more forms than necessary.  Thanks so much for posting this.