# How can I get both a model and HttpPostedFileBase into a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've looked quite a bit online, and every example I see explains how to get `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>` into a controller, OR how to get a model, but not both.

What I want is something like:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="Stored file name>
    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

with controller

```
[ActionName("Index"), HttpPost]
public ActionResult IndexPost(Models.MyModel mdl, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    // Do some something with the data in mdl and files here
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

But every way I try to implement this, it comes back 'no parameterless handler found'. It works fine if I *don't* include the model.

Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: Post the definition for `MyModel` (sounds like you have do not have a parameterless constructor for `MyModel`)

Comment: your form element's `name` property must match with your `MyModel` class, your `<input type="text" name="Stored file name>` has a syntex error and the property name must not content the spaces, so that you must specify the input name property as per the model property name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you couldn't find [Darin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc-3-0?lq=1). It's not exactly about passing model with HttpPostedFileBase but if you undrerstand the behavior the it's easy to do that.

See below example.

**View**

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.MyModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

**Action Method**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(MyModel model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                //do your stuff here
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: I did actually find this - what happened was that I had the issue originally, tried a bunch of fixes, no luck, but I *did* fix my initial problem, but re-broke it with one of the other 'fixes'. Doh :P