# Fileupload to server and saving his id to database as guid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

A client of mine came with the following demand:

- Add the option to upload a file to the server
- Save the file id as a guid in database

I followed this answer- so the file upload is working(to a specific location on the server)
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc-3-0`

What i don't familiar with is his second demand:
`Save the file id as a guid in database`

- What does it mean?
- Why does the file need a guid id in the database?
- What should I do in extra to the post I linked to?(security check, extension check?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guid = globaly unique identifier.

Why does a file need a guid in database ? well because its your client's requirement its not required by the database.

And finally how to do it? is simple when you will be saving a filename to database generate a guid and save it to the database you can generate a guid like this `Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();` and you can create a separate column in the database for saving file's guids.

Comment: Oh so, he just meant the file name to be encrypt? * also, what should i do in extra to this kind of task? security check etc`

Comment: not encrypted but i guess he wanted them to be unique and not easily guessable. i didn't understand the second part "security check"

Comment: sorry, i'll try to explain- what else should i do? i know its up to me but what are the "default" things i need to check for(like not allow to upload files that are bigger then 4 mb and specific extensions)

Comment: one other question - do you think a table like this is enough? columns "Id- int, FileName- guid, uploadDate- datetime"

Comment: it all depends on the requirements and type of files you are uploading, if you are uploading profile images you should only allow png/jpg you will have to see what your users are and how they are going to use your app and what is needed.