# multipart form - Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a ASP.NET MVC project that needs an API controller which will accept a posted multipart form and extract the data out of the `<formroot>` xml tag (which is highlighted)

I am struggling on getting this working any help would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Currently I have a controller called UploadController and this is the code I currently have

```
public class UploadController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        try
        {
            //Need to get the data from within the formroot tag


            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am unsure the best way to get the data from within the formroot, also forgive me if any of the code above is not correct.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Writing the POST? The controller? Analyzing the message? What code do you have already?

Comment: Apologies my question was vague, I will edit and flesh out now

Comment: It looks like you want to fetch the uploaded file data? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, as you can see from the image the XML from the post contains a bunch of fields that I need to extract the data from.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc-3-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the web API controller you can access the XML file by using the code below :-

```
HttpPostedFile xmlFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
```

If you have more than one files posted, replace Files[0] with respective count 1 or 2 etc.
Now you can load the file into a XmlDocument Object and extract the required node from it like :-

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xmlFile.InputStream);
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ab", "www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//ab:formroot", nsmgr);
```

Then you can perform whatever you functionality is provided with the node.

Comment: you sir are awesome! got me to where I needed thanks

Answer (score 0):

I always use solution below:

```
<form action="/Home/Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload" method="post">
      @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
      <input type="file" class="file" id="file" name="file" onchange="javascript:upload(this);" />
</form>
```

PS: "upload()" javascript function uses jquery to post the form.

```
function upload(obj) {
    var p = $(obj).parent();
    if (p.get(0).tagName != 'FORM') {
        p = p.parent();
    }
    p.submit();
}
```

In my controller i use as a modelbinder "HttpPostedFileBase".

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public RedirectResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    try
    {
        //physical path there you will save the file. 
        var path = @"c:\temp\filename.txt";
        file.SaveAs(path);
    }
    catch (UploadException ex)
    {

    }

    var url = "put here same url or another url";

    return RedirectResult(url);
}
```